# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_4 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 1188, 6)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have implemented a model using the following code.

```
model=models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.DepthwiseConv2D((3, 5), padding='valid', depth_multiplier=10, input_shape=(1188,1188,1)))


model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((3,3), strides=(1, 1)))
model.add(layers.Dropout(.2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.DepthwiseConv2D((2, 4), padding='valid', depth_multiplier=2))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(1, 1)))
model.add(layers.Dropout(.2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.DepthwiseConv2D((2, 2), padding='valid', depth_multiplier=2))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((3,2), strides=(1, 2)))
model.add(layers.Dropout(.2))
model.add(layers.Flatten())

model.add(layers.Dense(5))

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(f1, labels1,batch_size=20,epochs=10)
```

the shape of `f1` and `labels1` are `(1188, 1188, 6)`and `(1188, 1188, 1)` respectively.

after running it, i get this error-:  `ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_4 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 1188, 6)`

I also tried with `input shape=(1188,1188)` in the model.

but I got an error while running a model-: `ValueError: Input 0 of layer depthwise_conv2d is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 1188, 1188)`

Did I make a mistake while choosing a input shape?

if yes, what kinda modification i should do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass the data to your model in a batch with 4 dimensions. For example, if your batch size is 1, pass the input in this shape: (1,1188,1188,6).

edit:

In training a model in tensorflow, training datas should be passed to the model in a batch. A batch is a set of images(for example 64 images) which its first dimensions is batch size.

assume your dataset has 6400 images witch size of `28*28*3` and you set the batch size as 64, the you should give the training input to the model in shape of (64,28,28,3). For implementing this, you cand do the following:

```
import random
import numpy as np

for i in range(int(x_train.shape[0]/batch_size)):
          if len(list_of_samples) < batch_size:
            list_of_samples = [i for i in range(0, x_train.shape[0])]
          indexes = random.sample(list_of_samples, batch_size)
          for j in indexes:
            list_of_samples.remove(j)
          x_batch = x_train[indexes, :]
          y_true_batch = y_train[indexes]
          feed_dict = {x: x_batch, y_true: y_true_batch}
          session.run(optimizer, feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

Comment: could you explain a bit more? should i apply this or this is just an example?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).