# model params setup in tensorfllow in python

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

This is the modification of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70500209/valueerror-input-0-of-layer-sequential-4-is-incompatible-with-the-layer-expect/70500318#70500318).
I am posting this here separately.

I don't know about the input shape if it is correct or not. but after doing this it is giving me a different error that i mention below.

Here is my modified code.

```
model=models.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.DepthwiseConv2D((3, 5), padding='valid', depth_multiplier=10, input_shape=(400,400,6)))

model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((3,3), strides=(1, 1)))
model.add(layers.Dropout(.5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.DepthwiseConv2D((2, 4), padding='valid', depth_multiplier=2))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(1, 1)))
model.add(layers.Dropout(.5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.DepthwiseConv2D((2, 2), padding='valid', depth_multiplier=2))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((3,2), strides=(1, 2)))
model.add(layers.Dropout(.5))
model.add(layers.Flatten())

# model.add(layers.Dense(200, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(2))

model.summary()


model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss="categorical_crossentropy",
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(f1, labels1,batch_size=20,epochs=10)
```

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
depthwise_conv2d_3 (Depthwis (None, 398, 396, 60)      960       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 396, 394, 60)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 396, 394, 60)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
depthwise_conv2d_4 (Depthwis (None, 395, 391, 120)     1080      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_4 (MaxPooling2 (None, 394, 390, 120)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, 394, 390, 120)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
depthwise_conv2d_5 (Depthwis (None, 393, 389, 240)     1200      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_5 (MaxPooling2 (None, 391, 194, 240)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_5 (Dropout)          (None, 391, 194, 240)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 18204960)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 100)               1820496100
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 50)                5050      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 102       
=================================================================
Total params: 1,820,504,492
Trainable params: 1,820,504,492
Non-trainable params: 0

_________________________________________________________________
```

shape of `f1` and `label1` are `(1, 400, 400, 6), (1, 400, 400)`.

when i do 'model.fit' I am getting the following error-: `ValueError: Shapes (None, 400, 400) and (None, 2) are incompatible`

About the data-:

I am a CSV file, and there are 7 Columns(6(features)+ 1(label)) in it.

There are total 5 labels, but here you can see one label only

Total of 160000 entries are there. I added a sample of data.

[image: DATA]

this is the code i did for data preparing-:
I am doing for 2 labels only.

```
features=df[['a', 'a1', 'a2','b', 'b1', 'b2']].round(5).to_numpy(copy=True)    

labels=df["label"].to_numpy(copy=True)
      
# from features and labels, i took first 160000 entries by doing following.

f1=features[:160000].reshape(1,400,400,-1)

labels1=labels[:160000].reshape(-1,400,400)

print(np.unique(labels1)) #[0.  0.2]

f1.shape ,labels1.shape
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's your understanding of the above error? It simply tells you that, the target shape and model last layer shape is not shaped whereas they should be.

Comment: @M.Innat could you tell me what kind of modification i need to do?

Comment: what is the actual task, is it classification (`None, 5`) or segmentation (`None, 200, 200`)? Why the model's last layer output shape doesn't reflect the input target?

Comment: It's a classification task. there are 5 labels. could you suggest the modification, please? maybe with little explanation that i should know.

Comment: what is the label look like? Why it's in such shape (`None, 200, 200`). I get that here `None` refers to batch size. But what about others (`200, 200`).  It looks like it's the shape of some 2D sample/image.

Comment: @M.Innat I updated the question with the details of data. if you think I need to change the architecture, please suggest me.

Comment: what is the value count of label column, ie. df.labels.unique()? It only shows 0.0.

Comment: @M.Innat I just put that part only. but it is actually `[0. , 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8]` . it is after applying the `fit_transform`.

Comment: how did you prepare the data? Can you show us the code?

Comment: @M.Innat i modified a bit, and added the code of data processing. Here i am using 2 labels only. let me know if it is not understandable.

Comment: @M.Innat did i make mistake by choosing `loss`?

Comment: First issue I think here `labels1=labels[:160000].reshape(-1,400,400)`  whereas I think it should be `..reshape(1, -1)`. Second, you use loss fn categorical cross-entropy but your labels are not one-hot encoded. By seeing this `[0. , 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8]`, I think it's better to use binary cross-entropy.

Comment: @M.Innat i applied both sugeetions but i got this -: `  ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 160000 and 2 for '{{node binary_crossentropy/mul}} = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT](IteratorGetNext:1, binary_crossentropy/Log)' with input shapes: [?,160000], [?,2].`

Comment: @M.Innat and if i use  "categorical_crossentropy"  I get this-->> ` ValueError: Shapes (None, 160000) and (None, 2) are incompatible`